# Android SQlite Database Table has no column error

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, sql-insert

ERROR I am getting

```
SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting remark=remark userId=1 observation=observation qrcodeid=28100501010115P8BR2P91U9
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table _63 has no column named userId (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO _63(remark,userId,observation,qrcodeid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

I am inserting data in the database.

this is database Table

```
  public static final String Table_SEND_QR ="_63";
    public static final String COLUMN_SENDQR_ID63 = "sno";
    public static final String COLUMN_QRCode63 = "qrcodeid";
    public static final String COLUMN_Observation63 = "observation";
    public static final String COLUMN_Remark63 = "remark";
    public static final String COLUMN_UserId63 = "userId";
```

```
 String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE0000 = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_SEND_QR + "(" + COLUMN_SENDQR_ID63 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_QRCode63 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Observation63 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_Remark63 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_UserId63 + " TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE0000);
```

Insert method

```
public long InsertQR(String QRCodeid,String observation, String remark, String usrid)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_QRCode63,QRCodeid);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_Observation63,observation);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_Remark63,remark);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_UserId63,usrid);
        long result = db.insert(Table_SEND_QR,null,contentValues);
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```

These kinds of error are mostly due to some syntax error but I am unable to find one. Have a look and tell where I am mistaking

Comment: Have you added the column after running an earlier version of your app? If so, you can uninstall to get rid of the old database.

Comment: I did uninstalling and install again but the same problem.

Comment: Ok I Cleared the Cache and it did work. how to handle this issue if I want to make sure no error occurs when anybody updates this app?

Comment: If you're changing the schema of an app you've published, then you need to implement database versioning and schema migration code. Have a look at `SQLiteOpenHelper` `onUpgrade()`.